# How to override anaconda/kickstart package ordering?

Tags: linux, installation, rpm

I am building a bootable ISO to be used to install a Linux image (Oracle Linux, 5.8). This is using anaconda with a kickstart file to select the packages to be loaded. Some of these packages are failing with dependency problems in their %post section.

Eg, this is seen in /root/install.log after the installation is complete:

```
Installing thirdparty-tools-1.00-09.noarch
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.97891: line 1: ln: command not found
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.97891: line 2: ln: command not found
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.97891: line 3: ln: command not found
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.97891: line 4: ln: command not found
error: %post(thirdparty-tools-1.00-09.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 127
```

I'm trying to find out if it is possible to control/override the package ordering, *without editing any RPMs to add dependencies*. I've been looking through the anaconda / kickstart documentation (https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart#Chapter_3._Package_Selection), and searching extensively elsewhere, so I think that the answer is actually 'no, you can't do this'. Which would be a shame.

The problem is that I am trying to include various *third-party* RPMs, which are not under my control and which have been digitally signed. These include some processing in a %post section. This processing requires some standard Linux commands, eg 'ln', 'touch', etc, which are supplied within the coreutils package. The third-party package does not currently include a dependency on the coreutils package, though obviously it should really. Anaconda uses its own partial ordering algorithm to choose what order to install these packages, and the third-party packages are being installed *before* the coreutils package. Obviously, the *proper* solution is to get these RPMs fixed by the third-party; however, this is likely to take too long.

I was hoping that their might be some hidden / un-documented option for the kickstart file, which could add in extra dependencies. Ideally, I'd like to be able to add something like this to the %packages section:

```
%packages
@admin-tools
@base
@core
@system-tools
thirdparty-tools

# We would like to add some magic command to indicate a missing dependency
thirdparty-tools dependson coreutils
```

So, my question is: Is it possible to control or override the package ordering without editing any RPMs to add dependencies?

Very many thanks for any help.

Comment: Note that I asked the same question on the Unix/Linux StackExchange site here, and got a (partial) answer: [http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84237/how-to-override-anaconda-kickstart-package-ordering](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84237/how-to-override-anaconda-kickstart-package-ordering)

Answer (score 3):

If you can't get the source RPM, you can use rpmrebuild to re-create the RPM:

```
rpmrebuild -e -n -d . -p thirdparty-tools-1.00-09.noarch
```

This will bring up a re-created spec file in your default editor, where you can make changes to the requires lines.  Also, you may want to change the package name too, so that your re-built version is differentiated from the upstream vendor's version (I usually append "-local" to the package name).

Answer (score 1):

Your package "thirdparty-tools" needs to specify all of its requirements. If you can get a SRPM of this package, you can modify the spec to indicate that you need coreutils, bash, etc in your package.

If you can't modify this package at all, your best option is to create a wrapper package that has the necessary requirements. Just use your favorite editor to create a file "thirdparty-tools-installer.spec" and ensure you include coreutils as a requirement as well as "thirdparty-tools". You can refer to rpm.or for more information http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-build-creating-spec-file.html

Lastly, you can just do yum -y install thirdparty-tools in the %post section of Kickstart. It's uglier for sure, but it will probably work.

Comment: No, I am unable to edit thirdparty-tools RPM. A wrapper package still has the same problem; it can't ensure that the thirdparty-tools will be loaded _after_ its missing dependencies, though of course both would be loaded before this new wrapper package.